# Turbolister uses wrong account data internally

Tags: ebay

We have a new ebay account and imported some old tlb databases with old article data.

But when we upload we get some errors like "out of weekly limit" (this maybe a bad translation).

The point is that the error message suggests, the ebay account believes it is the old account, which it isn't, we use the name and the password of the new account.

And this only happens with the imported articels.

We tried "import" and "compact" and "repair" with the old databases, with no succes.

Is it possible that the articles still somehow have the old account information within them? And if so, how to fix it?

We had several phonecalls with ebay tech support, they have no idea, they checked our account and say everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the first auction manually in the web interface.

Comment: Any source for this information?

Comment: That was what solved it for me. Note this was in 2011.

Comment: I can remember this quite sure that exactly this workaround solved it, but things could have changed a lot since then.